# How to make a page scroll under a fixed container?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

the question is a bit more complex than the title can describe. I'm trying to make something like this:

There's a one page layout with content sections. Each section is 100vh, some of them are taller. When user scrolls down or swipes an animation occurrs sliding to a next section. When in a taller section user scrolls freely unless at the bounds of the section, then an animation occurrs.

I've come up with an idea that the browser's scrollbar should be something of a controller, that means it should indicate a position value that would be translated by JS to proper animation. I've created a fixed positioned container with the sections over page's body with its height set to the total sections height so the scrollbar indicates proper values.

The problem is I think I don't want the scrollbar to be visible, because it makes a little paradox when dragging it. Also there will be some content sliding in from the side with its own scrollbar. I think I can hide the scrollbar by doing some tricks if the scrollbar is in a div, not window, but it looks like when a fixed container is in a container with a scrollbar the scroll doesn't happen when the mouse is over the fixed container.

So now I'm stuck between having a window scrollbar and not being actually able to scroll over fixed container. I'd appreciate any help so much. Cheers!

some html just for codepen links to work:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="section-container">
    <div class="section"><h1>section 1</h1></div>
    <div class="section"><h1>section 2</h1></div>
    <div class="section"><h1>section 3</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen example with body scroll](http://codepen.io/KosmoGalaxy/pen/OXQJJk)

[codepen example with container scroll](http://codepen.io/KosmoGalaxy/pen/AXVBWj)

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You added scroll before fixed so it doesn't matter if you have scroll or not it is fixed so you cant scroll over fixed area only under.